# Is there an open-source technology similar to Google Hangouts?

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming

I'd like to build something similar for my app, and cannot find anything useful. I will need a video chat with groupings and a text chat.
If you used something similar, please let me know.

Comment: Have you looked at the webrtc tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Before Hangouts these was google talk which was bases around the open source XMPP protecol.